# ¿Cómo hacer que sólo se acepten números enteros? pero no puedo usar for,while o do while y tengo que introducir+ el numero

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el programa no deje poner letras o decimales?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
long fibo( long n );
    int main(){
    long r,n; 
    printf( "Introduzca su numero entero: " );
    scanf( "%ld", &n);   
    r= fibo(n);   
    if ( n % 2 == 0 )
    printf( "\n Fibonacci[%ld]=%ld y es par",n,r );
    else
    printf( "\n Fibonacci[%ld]=%ld y es impar",n,r );    
    return 0; 
    } 
    long fibo(long n)
    {
    if(n==0||n== 1)
    return n;
    else  
    return fibo(n-1)+fibo(n-2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sugiero que en vez de leer un numero realices la lectura de una cadena y luego validar con la librería regex si efectivamente el dato introducido es un numero entero, posteriormente convertirlo a int. Ahora esto no evita la introducción de un dato errado, simplemente te da la posibilidad de validar si el dato digitado es valido y así mostrar el error correspondiente.

Por otra parte scanf retorna el numero de elemento leidos correctamente, para tu caso si el valor digitado es un numero retornará 1, si es una letra retornará 0, el problema es si digitan un numero decimal, pues igualmente retornará 1, en ese caso solo la parte entera del numero digitado será leida, podrías en vez de leer un entero leer un decimal y comprobar si tiene o no parte decimal, de tener una parte decimal igualmente mostrar el error correspondiente.